# using php _GET within javascript function

Tags: javascript, php

I have some javascript embedded into an html file that I am running in a browswer.

```
document.getElementById('home-search-text-inp').value = <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['search_for']); ?>;
```

Why does this not fill the textbox?

Note that:

```
document.getElementById('home-search-text-inp').value = "hi";
```

puts "hi" into the textbox and:

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['search_for']); ?>
```

writes text just fine.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems like 50% of the questions you ask involve embedding PHP within JavaScript. This is not something you should have to so frequently. First off, check your JavaScript console. Do you see errors? `ReferenceError: hi is not defined`. Yep, that's what you would see if you actually checked it. Now go check your JavaScript source. What's the problem there? A glaring syntax error because there's an unquoted string. StackOverflow is not for syntax errors. You'd see them more easily if you stopped trying to embed PHP in everything you do with JS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing quotes around your string value:

```
document.getElementById('home-search-text-inp').value = <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['search_for']); ?>;
                                                      ^^^^                                                  ^^^^                                                      
                                                      HERE                                                  HERE
```

should be:

```
document.getElementById('home-search-text-inp').value = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['search_for']); ?>";
```

Comment: @JohnConde this is a pretty fragile solution. Double quotes luckily work here but single quotes would cause a JavaScript error if the user searched for `cat's cradle`. I would recommend explicitly json-encoding the value for a more robust solution.